# QGIS Oracle connection succeeded but never ends?

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I created a new connection with the Oracle database, when I Press 'test connection', I have a msg that the connection succeeded, but after that, when I click OK, the connection process never ends, it stays working forever, (I end up killing the process), is there any solution for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that QGIS decided to to a full table scan of all tables in your schema - or even possibly all tables accessible to your user. That can take quite a while.

Check out the settings for your connection. Here are the settings I use:
[image]

The most important setting is "Use estimated table metadata" which avoids scanning the entire table. The other one is "Only look for user tables" which makes it check only those tables that are owned by the current user. If not, and depending on the privileges of your user, it could end up checking **ALL TABLES** in your database: hopefully you did not grant SELECT ANY TABLE to your user. Or even worse DBA ...

See more on this in the QGIS documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#connecting-to-oracle-spatial

[image]